# Windows Partition to EFI Boot

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition, big-sur

I’ve been using Windows 10 via Boot Camp and it worked fine. I’m not sure if there’s any relation since I just noticed recently, but I upgraded my OS to macOS Big Sur and my Windows Partition became EFI Boot. Whenever I try to access it, Windows logo just shows and loads for a bit then restarts to start Mac OS.

Comment: If you Mac is capable of running Big Sur, then Boot Camp probably installed Windows 10 to EFI Boot. Did you perhaps first install an older BIOS booting Windows, then upgrade to Windows 10?